# html 3 row layout using div's

Tags: html, css, layout, web

I have 3 rows header,footer and content but my content div is too large and makes the window to scroll. how do I put the content fixed between header and footer and how do I change the height so that is does not have to scroll the window

my index.php

```
<body> 
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">

    </div>
    <div id="content">

    </div>
    <div id="footer">

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

my css

```
 body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div#header{
width:100%;
height:65px;
position:relative;
top:0;
background-color:#F00;
 } 

div#footer{
width:100%;
height:65px;
position:relative;
bottom:0;
background-color:#06F;
}
div#content{
background-color:#9F0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
    }
```

this is how it looks at the top: [link](http://i45.tinypic.com/2u6k955.png)

this is how it loks after scrolling at the bottom :[link 2](http://i50.tinypic.com/jqomzp.png)

I want the header(red), footer(blue), and content(green) to come in 100% height so that I don't have to scroll

Comment: have you tried changing the height of div#content to be something like 95%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you want.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w7R5D/1/)

**In your code i edited-**

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
div#header{
width:100%;
height:65px;
position:fixed;
z-index:100;
background-color:#F00;
 } 

div#footer{
width:100%;
height:65px;
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
background-color:#06F;
}
div#content{
background-color:#111;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:absolute;
    }
```

Comment: This just displays the header and footer div "above" the content div and hides it partially. Looks right on first side but when you add content to the content-div it is hidden by the header.

Comment: @Casey The solution to that is to add top and bottom margin to the content div that match the height of the footer and header http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/w7R5D/137/

Answer (score 2):

You will need to tell the body to also be 100% high so the table can then stretch to the window size, then define the body as the table, and each div as a row.

css:

```
html,
body {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#header,
#footer {
    background: #ff0000;
    display: table-row;
    height: 65px;
}

#content {
    background: #000;
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<body> 
    <div id="header">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="content">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="footer">&nbsp;</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the header and footer height 10%, and the content 80%.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your content div as follows:

```
div#content{
background-color:#9F0;
width:100%;
height:80%;
overflow:auto;
}
```

if it doesn't work try height:700px;

Answer (score 0):

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    html,
    body {
       margin:0;
       padding:0;
       height:100%;
    }
    #container {
       min-height:100%;
       position:relative;
    }
    #header {
       background:#ff0;
       padding:10px;
       height:150px;    
    }
    #body {
       padding:10px;
       padding-bottom:260px;   /* Height of the footer */
    }
    #footer {
       position:absolute;
       bottom:0;
       width:100%;
       height:260px;   /* Height of the footer */
       background:#6cf;
    }


    </style>
    <script>

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
       <div id="header"></div>
       <div id="body">
    </div>
       <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This code supports the unfixed content div.Only footer height has to be fixed.This the best code i came across till date.