# 3 row layout with signin-box using html, divs and css

Tags: html, css, layout, web

Using HTML, CSS and DIVs, I like to create a 3 row layout, like: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15016862/html-3-row-layout-using-divs).

Additionally I need a signin-box with a fixed width in the top right of the first row.

I tried that:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="signin"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>

body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
div#top {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:65px;
    z-index:100;
    background-color:#AAA;
}
div#header {
    width:100%;
    height:65px;
    background-color:#F00;
    float:left;
}
div#signin {
    width:100px;
    height:65px;
    background-color:#0F0;
    float:right;
}
div#footer {
    width:100%;
    height:65px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#06F;
}
div#content {
    background-color:#111;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
```

But the login box is placed below the first row; see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w7R5D/190/).

How can I place the login box at the right of the first row? TIA!

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/w7R5D/191/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `positon:absolute;` and `right:0px;` to `signin` selector
try this

```
div#signin {
    width:100px;
    height:65px;
    background-color:#0F0;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w7R5D/192/)** here

Comment: @ezaz, you are right, float:right is not required as I am positioning it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple code move signin div inside header div

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="top">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="signin"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your `<div id="signin"></div>` inside `<div id="header"></div>`

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="signin"></div>
</div>
```